# looking for alternatives to lysol wipes (Alkyl C12-18 dimethyl benzyl ammonium chloride)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

Lysol and other recommended disinfectants claiming virucidal properties have been basically impossible to find here for weeks. I did however, find a bottle of clorox all-purpose disinfecting cleaner with the same active ingredient as my lysol wipes (dimethyl benzyl ammonium chloride) with a .3% concentration as opposed to Lysol's .26%.

https://clorox.ca/products/sprays/clorox-all-purpose-disinfecting-cleaner-spray/

I've been doing as much research as a chemistry inept mechanical engineer can to find studies on the active ingredient and viruses, with mixed reviews, and am turning to you for help. I'm wondering if i follow similar instructions to lysol's (wet for 10 minutes before air drying) with this product, am I going to achieve the same effect, or is that not necessarily the case? Is the lack of indication and instructions on the packaging for virucidal disinfectant what's holding it back from making it onto the EPA and canadian equivalent lists, or could there be a legitimate reason they cant make that claim?

I know this is a long-shot, but any insight you might share would be greatly appreciated in these interesting times.

Comment: This is medical advice which is [off-topic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Consult your doctor instead.

Comment: I'd love to, the main problem is doctors tend to be fairly busy during global pandemics, and had you read the question, you'd know it was specific to finding more information about a specific compound, which i doubt my doctor knows all that much about... My doctor being a neurologist because I have MS which puts me in a high risk group, hence i'm spending so long to see if what i have might actually be useful. But sure I get it, you're a very important person who only has time to be negative rather than just ignore something.

Comment: I'm not trying to be negative. Your question was downvoted because you are a new contributor to this Q&A site and do not know (yet) what is considered off-topic. We don't like medical-related questions to be asked here, hence it was my duty as a member to flag it as medical advice. I understand you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely standard chemistry perspective, the longer one allows a potentially slow reaction (attack of the outer membranes, for example) to occur, I would expect better results.

Photochemistry is also an option to consider, which may be catalytic with other treatments. In particular, explore safe natural light sun bulbs (I would select the higher output, again intensity matters) and any comments relative to benefits you seek.

There are also reputedly disinfecting air filters available (again check reagents and reviews), which is probably the best idea.

Comment: thanks for the response, very good ideas to consider.

I will also keep digging on the subject compound. I did find a handful of studies (and others i cannot access) with varying conclusions as to the effectiveness on enveloped viruses, the consensus being not as effective as you'd hope. it just boggles me, how then, these lysol wipes can make the 99.99% claim. perhaps a mechanical effect of the wipes in addition to the disinfectant, or a non-active ingredient catalyst? Just odd because i've also found some studies about how the wipes may be detrimental to the solution's effectiveness